# What is a good introductory text on resampling methods?

Tags: references, bootstrap, resampling, subsampling, jackknife

I have found a few decent ones about specific resampling applications such as bootstrapped confidence intervals, but nothing broader. A journal article or book chapter would be preferable to an entire book, but all recommendations are welcome.

Edit: I am looking for an article or chapter that provides an overview of the wider range of resampling methods (e.g., bootstrapping, jackknifing, subsampling) rather than a treatment of just one.

Comment: I used [Bootstrap Methods and their Application](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/bootstrap-methods-and-their-application/ED2FD043579F27952363566DC09CBD6A) by Davison and Hinkley in the past a lot; it is very good.

Comment: The Davison and Hinkley book is also very good. It came out after Efron and Tibshirani and before my first book. I am sure that there are references given in many treads on this site.

Comment: I would argue against that duplicate as my question is about all resampling methods and asks for introductory articles/chapters rather than a textbook.

Comment: I am not familiar with a 2013 version of the text nor do I know what schnitz means.

Comment: I might note that the jackknife is also a resampling method due to Tukey that predates all the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at:

- Philip Good's book on resampling methods titled "Permutation Tests";
- my texts on bootstrap methods published by Wiley, e.g. "Bootstrap Methods: A Guide for Practitioners", first edition in 1999 and the second edition in 2007; "An Introduction to Bootstrap Methods with Applications to R" co-authored with Robert A. LaBudde in 2011;
- classic book by Efron titled "The Bootstrap, the Jackknife and Other Resampling Plans".

Comment: The OP is welcome to check my answer if he so chooses or can wait to here more answers that may be given.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Can you please provide the complete references and then I will accept the answer.

Comment: It is a long list you can find on amazon.  Tukey's original work is not in a book.  It is in a monograph by Efron published by SIAM in 1979. A theoretical text "Bootstrap and Edgeworth Expansions" was authored by Peter Hall in 1982 with Springer-Verlag as the publisher.

Comment: Please at least provide the title of each recommendation (i.e., the one by Good, one or more of your texts, and the monograph by Efron and Tibshirani). Otherwise the answer has the potential to confuse readers.

Comment: The monograph by Efron did not include Tibshirani.  The title is "The Bootstrap, the Jackknife and Other Resampling Plans". Phil Good's text is called "Permutation Tests" and my books are all published by Wiley "Bootstrap Methods: A Guide for Practitioners".  My first edition was in 1999 and the second edition in 2007. I have one other publication. "An Introduction to Bootstrap Methods with Applications to R" coauthored with Robert A. LaBudde.in 2011.